# Copy external json data and paste in local json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, clone

I have a bunch of widgets on my admin interface one of which is weather. Based on how my admin interface is coded it reloads every 60sec. Which is too many api calls per minute for weather. To change only the weather widget refresh rate is gonna take a lot, so thought it would be easier if i copy the data from the openweathermap.org every 60min and place the data in a local json that can be accessed by my weatehr widget instead of making so many api calls to the external source.

How can i use jquery, javascript or php to copy data looking like the following,from a website address to a local JSON file?

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":296.2,"pressure":1023,"humidity":69,"temp_min":294.82,"temp_max":297.15},"wind":{"speed":1.5},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1473178865,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0074,"country":"GB","sunrise":1473139361,"sunset":1473186795},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Comment: do you mean to write a json file using javascript?

Comment: use angular or react js for it.

Comment: @user2181397 Yes copy the data from the external source and write it to a json file. I doubt i'll be able to use JS but i might be able to use ajax or php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommended you to create a scheduled task that run every 60s to get the weather data via the api, then store the data into a local file and redirect the admin interface to read from that file, not the api

You can use cron jobs to create a scheduled task for retrieving the data from the api.

here is a sample code for retrieving the weather data from the api using PHP and store the result to a text file.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=79191467e423ba376b1b72529788eeb8",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

  $weather_data = ($response);
  // save $weather_data to local file
  $file = 'weather_data.txt';

  // Write the contents to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $weather_data);
}
```

Comment: you obviously didn't read my question properly and just wanted to post something. I also need 60min not 60sec. You have essentially repeated everything i had already indicated. You have not provided a proper solution as requested in my question. I will Flag your post!

Comment: sorry for that, i update my post with a sample code for retrieving the data and store it in a file

Comment: The file was saved using the code provided, but there's no data in it!

Comment: try to replace $weather_data = json_decode($response); with $weather_data = $response; because the returned data is already in json format, see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function() {


function httpGet()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var theUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            saveTextAsFile(xmlhttp.responseText);
        };
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}



function saveTextAsFile(textToSave )
{


    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "weather.json";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}




httpGet();

})();
```

Just invoke it a after loading http://api.openweathermap.org (or include loading it in the code..) and add your API key in the script's url...

Comment: this code works by comping creating and downloading the file. But how do i actually save the file to a directory on my server?

Comment: That depends a bit on the browser you are using. One way is to switch the browser's download folder to the (maybe mounted) folder where the JSON file should be located.